# In C++, how do I reuse a static member function in a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-methods, derived-class

I have a `class Edge {};`, with a member function `static Edge* findEdge(Node n1*, Node* n2);`. I also have two derived classes `class PhysicalLink : Edge {};` and `class LogicalLink : Edge{};`. For any pair of nodes n1 and n2 I want to have the possibility to find the corresponding PhysicalLink and LogicalLink objects, resp., based on what `Edge::findEdge()` returns, either by some smart type casting, or by writing  a wrapper function in either derived class, or or or... What's the best (or only) way to do something like that?

Here is a code snippet that compiles, for further clarification:

```
class Edge;  // Forward declaration

class Node {}; 

class Graph
{
public:
    static std::vector<Edge> getEdges() { return edges; }

private:
    static std::vector<Edge> edges;
};

class Edge
{
public:
    Edge() = default;
    Edge(Node* n1, Node* n2) : _n1(n1), _n2(n2) {}
    static Edge* findEdge(Node* n1, Node* n2) { return &Graph::getEdges().at(0); }  // placeholder definition, in reality a function of n1 and n2

private:
    Node* _n1;
    Node* _n2;
};

class PhysicalLink : Edge
{
    static PhysicalLink* findPhysicalLink(Node* n1, Node* n2) { return new PhysicalLink; }  // placeholder definition, I want to know how to use findEdge() here
};

class LogicalLink : Edge
{
    static LogicalLink* findLogicalLink(Node* n1, Node* n2) { return new LogicalLink; }  // placeholder definition, I want to know how to use findEdge() here
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So, what exactly are you having trouble with?  How are your `Node`s related to `Edge`s? `findEdge()` returns an `Edge*`, so it can return a pointer to any object that derives from `Edge`. The caller shouldn't care what type of `Edge` is returned, but if it does, it can use `dynamic_cast` to figure out the type.

Comment: Please show your code ([mcve])

Comment: @RemyLebeau: so are you saying I should do it like this:

```PhysicalLink* findPhysicalLink(Node* n1, Node *n2)
{
     return dynamic_cast<PhysicalLink*>(findEdge(n1, n2));
}```

?

Comment: You could do that, yes. If you absolutely need to return a `PhysicalLink*` specifically and not a generic `Edge*`.  In this case, `dynamic_cast<PhysicalLink*>` will return `nullptr` if `findEdge()` does not return a pointer to a `PhysicalLink` object.

Comment: Thanks everybody, next time please grant a little bit of time to provide sample code before closing the question. Thanks :)

Comment: you can take all the time you need to prepare an example before posting ;)